# Windows permissions syncronization

Tags: windows, windows-8, sync, file-permissions

I borrowed an original Surface RT to try it out. I was granted administrative rights to the device with my Microsoft account (@outlook.com) and logged in.

Many months later the owner of the Surface RT reported that now on his home computer (which I have never touched) has my user with Read & Execute permissions on his c:\Users\UserName folder.

Is there any reason that permissions from a Surface would propogate/sync to another computer automatically? The owner of the Surface logs into the Surface and  his home computer with the same Microsoft account.

Is there some part of the Microsoft account that syncs not only things like desktop backgrounds but also file and folder permissions across devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You and the previous owner should open up PC Settings, Accounts, Your Account and tap the "More account settings online" link.

In the resulting web page, you can see any "related accounts" to see if you're somehow tied to each other there.

Finally, you can check if OneDrive is backing up your settings, and ask him if he restored them (search for sync, select sync settings).

I haven't come across this problem before, so this is more of an investigation suggestion than an answer...

Answer (score 0):

So first off - it is obvious that something has gone horribly wrong here. Whatever caused this is a huge security hole, you should not have an account on your friends computer unless you used remote desktop to log into it, or logged into it directly.

That being said, your permissions could have something to do with onedrive/skydrive's remote file access feature.

You can read about it a bit here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/onedrive/fetch-files-pc-ui

From what I've read, this feature has largely been killed - but in theory, it could have changed permissions to allow you to remotely access files if somehow these settings were synced between the RT tablet and the Desktop computer.